# How will, I remove Two coma using split and splice method in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have create a sentence "my name , is , shahab". I want to remove both comma's.
I removed one comma.Can any one help me to remove the other comma and show the  sentence "my name is shahab".

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Helpful functions</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div>
  <h2>Hello my name is Babloo</h2>
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">

  let alpha = "my name , is , shahab";
  let al = alpha.split(" ");
  let index = al.findIndex((c)=>{
   return c == ','
  })
  al.splice(index,1)

  alpha = al.join(" ");
  console.log(alpha)


 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I wonder why the question was downvoted? Sure it may be a dupe, but it's a well asked question

Comment: To be clear, do you **have** to use `split`? Or are you OK to use regex with replace function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid using `split` and `splice`. Simply, use `replace` in global scope

**USING REPLACE**

```js
var str = 'my name , is , shahab';
var res = str.replace(/\, /g, '');
console.log(res);
```

**USING SPLIT AND JOIN**

```js
let str = "my name , is , shahab";
var res  = str.split(',').join('');
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Why are you escaping the comma in your regex? It's not a metacharacter.

Comment: Question specifically ask for using split and splice, perhaps you should clarify with the OP if regex is acceptable first

Comment: @musefan I know that but since I am giving answer to help the OP and optimize his code. I preferred to give this.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal: And what if the OP is not permitted to use regex? Then your answer is useless... best to check first rather than presume

Comment: @musefan Where in the question does it specifically ask that?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen: The title... you know, the big text at the top...

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen and musefan. I have edited my answer with both. OP can check for both.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal: Fair enough... though I personally don't like having to click a link to see 3 lines of code, but that's just my opinion

Comment: @musefan I somehow overlooked that. Thanks for your kind and clarifying remark.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen: No problem... just wanted to help you locate exactly where it was

Comment: splice do not make sense. Split and join will make proper sense. What do you say?

Comment: @musefan Your efforts are sincerely appreciated.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen what do you think the answer should be upvoted or downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

You can split by ,(comma) into arrays and then join them

```js
let alpha = "my name , is , shahab";
alpha = alpha.split(",").join("");
console.log(alpha);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either call .replace(‘,’, ””) twice or preferably write your own replaceAll function using regular expressions:

```
function(search, replacement) {
    return this.replace(new RegExp(search, ‘g’), replacement);
}
```

Comment: Call replace twice?? What if there are 3 commas?

Comment: Plz can you type conmplete code.